# Numpy, making from a shape (5,) a 3D shape

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, dimensions

I have a numpy array with shape (5,). However inside every element of this array is another 2D np array. It ended up like this as I vertically stacked rows onto a matrix(where every column had different dimension). So basically the matrix with shape (5,) is 1 column of this matrix. Now my questions: is it possible to make this into a 3d np array? I need it to pass it into Tensorflow. Thanks in Advance!

Stephan

Comment: What's the shapes of those 5 2d arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.stack(x)` and friends.  This will transform any sequence of arrays into a single array with one more dimension.